# Python: Get minutes overlap between time range

Tags: python, python-datetime

```
date_base_start = datetime(2013, 07, 17, 20, 0) #July 17,2013 08:00PM
date_base_end = datetime(2013, 07, 17, 22, 0)   #July 17,2013 10:00PM

date_1_start = datetime(2013, 07, 17, 21, 0)    #July 17,2013 09:00PM
date_1_end = datetime(2013, 07, 17, 21, 30)     #July 17,2013 09:30PM

date_2_start = datetime(2013, 07, 17, 19, 0)    #July 17,2013 07:00PM
date_2_end = datetime(2013, 07, 17, 23, 0)      #July 17,2013 11:00PM

date_3_start = datetime(2013, 07, 17, 19, 0)    #July 17,2013 07:00PM
date_3_end = datetime(2013, 07, 17, 22, 0)      #July 17,2013 10:00PM

#Expected Result date_base_start, date_base_end VS the ff:
#     date_1_start, date_1_end : 30min
#     date_2_start, date_2_end : 120min
#     date_3_start, date_3_end : 120min
```

What python datetime manipulation is needed to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
delta = min(date_1_end,date_base_end)-max(date_1_start,date_base_start)
#
# Check if delta is negative, 
#
if delta.seconds < 0:
         print 0
else:
         print delta.seconds/60.0
```

Comment: nice answer! thanks. it same with my solution below. But I like the use of min, max function. awesome!

Comment: thanks, I also love how versatile min and max are, they just need any objects that can be compared, I think.

Comment: `delta.seconds< 0` gives incorrect result when delta is a large time interval. `delta.total_seconds()< 0` might be a safer one.

Answer (score 2):

```
def overlap(range1,range2):
    start_datetime = max(range1[0],range2[0])
    end_datetime   = min(range1[1],range2[1])
    return end_datetime-start_datetime

print overlap([date_base_start,date_base_end],[date_3_start, date_3_end])
```

Comment: you can't to it that why. date_3_end - date_3_start will give you 180min difference

Answer (score 2):

```
def minutes_overlap_test(date_base_start, date_base_end, date_comp_start, date_comp_end):
    tmp_start = date_base_start
    tmp_end = date_base_end

    if date_comp_start > tmp_start:
        tmp_start = date_comp_start
    if date_comp_end < tmp_end:
        tmp_end = date_comp_end

    d1_ts = time.mktime(tmp_start.timetuple())
    d2_ts = time.mktime(tmp_end.timetuple())
    return int(d2_ts-d1_ts) / 60
```

This is all the solution I've got. Any enhancement on this?